# Derivation of Coulomb's constant

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law, physical-constants

I am searching for the derivation of the [Coulomb constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_constant).
In most of the parts of internet, they just explain the experiment, and How force is proportional to $q1q2$, and Force is inversely proportional to $r^2$. But I can not find the mathematical method of Coulomb of the derivation of $k$ from the data he gathered or  when and how the value of $k$ was first determined, historically. Of course, one can explain its derivation by Using later theories. But if Coulomb  states there is a proportional constant then there must be his attempt to derive it. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Was it not determined experimentally?

Comment: You might have some luck over on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). I didn't look for more than a minute, but [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5519/13342) could have some useful reference?

Comment: I think you are unfamiliar with the determination of the Coulomb's constant and the Universal Gravitational constant using Torsion balance!!  You can watch it now, just search it on youtube!

Comment: @Fardin, I am familiar with the torsion balance experiment, as I stated in my quesiton post that I can only find the explanation and the demonstration  of the experiment (meaning the Torsion Balance experiment) and Coulomb's proportionalities that he has identified. I was asking if there is anywhere in the cyber space the step by step  derivation  that k is 1/4pi*epsilon not

Comment: @DhruvKaushik, Indeed it was! However, it is only stated that it was determined experimentally but not explained in  great detail the mathematics behind of how he determined it experimentally.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, Thank you  a lot! I found a great article giving some insight about how  Coulomb assumes the same analogy of  the gravitational universal constant  behind the  Coulomb's constant.